# How to solve 'right-hand operand has no effect' error?

Tags: c

I am currently working with Eclipse CDT, the [ESP-IDF](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/) framework and the [ESP32 Wrover DevKit](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/hw-reference/get-started-wrover-kit.html).

I was looking for a `C` vector implementation and stumbled over [rxi/vec on GitHub](https://github.com/rxi/vec). I copied `vec.h` and `vec.c` to my project and tried to compile. I am getting the following error:

```
Error: right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect[-Werror=unused-value]
```

... at this line of code in `vec.h`:

```
#define vec_push(v, val)\
  ( vec_expand_(vec_unpack_(v)) ? -1 :\
    ((v)->data[(v)->length++] = (val), 0), 0 )
```

Any ideas how solve this issue or work around? Any alternative vector implementation for `C` ?

---

### Update A

```
../main/tools/inc/vec.h:35:42: error: right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
   ( vec_expand_(vec_unpack_(v)) ? -1 :\
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
     ((v)->data[(v)->length++] = (val), 0), 0 )
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
../main/main.c:44:2: note: in expansion of macro 'vec_push'
  vec_push(&toc.items, item1);
  ^~~~~~~~
../main/tools/inc/vec.h:35:42: error: right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
   ( vec_expand_(vec_unpack_(v)) ? -1 :\
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
     ((v)->data[(v)->length++] = (val), 0), 0 )
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
../main/main.c:50:2: note: in expansion of macro 'vec_push'
  vec_push(&item1.elements, elem1);
  ^~~~~~~~
../main/tools/inc/vec.h:35:42: error: right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
   ( vec_expand_(vec_unpack_(v)) ? -1 :\
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
     ((v)->data[(v)->length++] = (val), 0), 0 )
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
../main/main.c:56:2: note: in expansion of macro 'vec_push'
  vec_push(&item1.elements, elem2);
  ^~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

---

### Update B

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "vec.h"

typedef struct toc_element_t {
  uint16_t uid;
  char element[8];
  char type[8];
} toc_element_t;

typedef vec_t(toc_element_t) vec_toc_element_t;

typedef struct toc_item_t {
  char category[8];
  vec_toc_element_t elements;
} toc_item_t;

typedef vec_t(toc_item_t) vec_toc_item_t;

typedef struct toc_t {
    char description[8];
    vec_toc_item_t items;
} toc_t;


void app_main(void) {

    toc_t toc;
    strcpy(toc.description, "toc1");
    vec_init(&toc.items);

    toc_item_t item1;
    strcpy(item1.category, "cat1");
    vec_init(&item1.elements);
    vec_push(&toc.items, item1);

    toc_element_t elem1;
    elem1.uid=0;
    strcpy(elem1.element, "elem1");
    strcpy(elem1.type, "float");
    vec_push(&item1.elements, elem1);

    toc_element_t elem2;
    elem2.uid=1;
    strcpy(elem2.element, "elem2");
    strcpy(elem2.type, "float");
    vec_push(&item1.elements, elem2);


    printf("TOC [%s]:\n", toc.description);

    toc_item_t item; int index1;
    vec_foreach(&toc.items, item, index1) {
        printf(" - item[%d]=%s\n", index1, item.category);
        toc_element_t element; int index2;
        vec_foreach(&item.elements, element, index2) {
            printf("  - element[%d]=%s [%s]\n", index2, element.element, element.type);
        }
    }

    while(1);

}
```

---

### Update C

Perhaps this issue is not related to this question, but since Eric mentioned the last commit with the log message “Fixed vec_insert() and vec_push() for structs” that inserted the 'fishy' `,0` that caused the problem discussed here, it may nonetheless be related.

When executing the code in section "Update B", I get the following output:

```
TOC [toc1]:
 - item[0]=cat1
```

But I would expect the following:

```
TOC [toc1]:
 - item[0]=cat1
  - element[0]=elem1
  - element[1]=elem2
```

Solved: [Why does the inner vector not get printed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645307/why-does-the-inner-vector-not-get-printed-out/60645590#60645590)

Comment: @KamilCuk : Yes, there's more information, I am sorry not having posted earlier. I updated the OP.

Comment: There's actually nothing wrong with that code. Investigate your IDE/compiler to see how to turn off that warning. In generally that's really bad advice, but in this particular case it's right.

Comment: `Any ideas how solve this issue or work around?` remove `-Werror=unused-value` from your compiler options. The code is valid. The `Any alternative vector implementation in C` is an offtopic question for stackoverflow, but anyway [g_array](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html).

Comment: You haven't told us the whole story. See [mcve].

Comment: The compiler is right to warn you. Something is fishy there. The `… ? -1 : (…, 0)` part is designed to return a success/failure indication, and then the trailing `, 0` throws that away. It is “valid code” in that it does not violate a rule of the C standard, but there is clearly a design or coding error there. Perhaps there are clues in the edit history or in other uses of the macro.

Comment: I will post a sample in a couple of minutes - thanks for helping me!

Comment: Okay, I now have added a minimal reproducible example in section "Update B".

Comment: it seems like you have different ideas of *minimal*: i have almost-none of the header-files you use, i wouldn't know how to *verify*. could you create an example without any external libraries (FreeRTOS, ESP,..)?

Comment: @umläute : You are right, I am sorry. I now have reduced the example.

Comment: Something to try. Declare a variable `int status;` and then change all of the `vec_push(...);` lines to `status = vec_push(...);` Let us know what the compiler has to say about that.

Comment: You can also try removing the final `, 0` from the macro, to see if that changes how the compiler reacts. The final `, 0` seems wrong, for the reason explained in Eric's comment.

Comment: I would avoid all the macro shenanigans by changing to an inline function

Comment: @user3386109 Now the program compiles without errors by using your suggested approaches (either with `int status;` or by removing the last `, 0` ). Thank you!

Comment: The extra `, 0` was introduced in commit dd55e00e17d454f54b905fdcf6718ba0c1ed94b0, with the log message “Fixed vec_insert() and vec_push() for structs”. It and the same change to `vec_insert` are the only changes in that commit, and I do not see how it comports with the log message. I think it is a mistake.

Comment: @salocinx Glad to hear it. Now someone just needs to fix the macro in the GitHub project.

Comment: @user3386109 Alright, I am quite new to C and Github, but I guess I need to make a fork and then change this stuff and finally make a pull request. I will try to do that :-)

Comment: @user3386109 Pull request initiated: https://github.com/rxi/vec/pull/12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is right to warn you. Something is fishy there. The `… ? -1 : (…, 0)` part is designed to return a success/failure indication, and then the trailing `, 0` throws that away. It is “valid code” in that it does not violate a rule of the C standard, but there is clearly a design or coding error there.

The extra `, 0` was introduced in commit dd55e00e17d454f54b905fdcf6718ba0c1ed94b0, with the log message “Fixed vec_insert() and vec_push() for structs”. It and the same change to `vec_insert` are the only changes in that commit:

```
--- a/src/vec.h
+++ b/src/vec.h
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@

 #define vec_push(v, val)\
   ( vec_expand_(vec_unpack_(v)) ? -1 :\
-    ((v)->data[(v)->length++] = (val)), 0 )
+    ((v)->data[(v)->length++] = (val), 0), 0 )


 #define vec_pop(v)\
@@ -52,7 +52,7 @@

 #define vec_insert(v, idx, val)\
   ( vec_insert_(vec_unpack_(v), idx) ? -1 :\
-    ((v)->data[idx] = (val)), (v)->length++, 0 )
+    ((v)->data[idx] = (val), 0), (v)->length++, 0 )
```

I do not see how those changes comport with the log message. I think it is a mistake. Note that the pre-commit code was wrong; this code:

```
  ( vec_expand_(vec_unpack_(v)) ? -1 :\
    ((v)->data[(v)->length++] = (val)), 0 )
```

has the pattern `(Test ? -1 : (Operation), 0)`. That always produces 0, since the comma operator is the lowest precedence. The commit changes it to `(Test ? -1 : (Operation, 0), 0)`, which has equivalent behavior—on the `:` side, the operation is performed, but then the result is discarded, 0 is evaluated and discarded, and then there is another 0. If the commit had changed it to `(Test ? -1 : (Operation, 0))`, that would make sense. The commit would be fixing an error, in that the macro previously always produced 0 but would now produce 0 or −1 according to whether the operation was successful or not.

None of the tests in the repository check the “return” value of `vec_push`.

It should be safe to remove the `, 0`. The resulting expansion will continue to evaluate to zero in normal situations. It will change to evaluate to −1 if the push fails (because memory allocation fails), but that would seem to be desirable. Good code should be:

```
#define vec_push(v, val)\
  ( vec_expand_(vec_unpack_(v)) ? -1 :\
    ((v)->data[(v)->length++] = (val), 0))
```

Also make the same change to `vec_insert` and look for any similar code that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answer! I am not quite sure which `, 0` to remove in `vec_insert`; the first or second one? I added another section "Update C" in my OP. Is this maybe related?

Comment: I opened an issue on Github ealier, I will link this discussion over there.

Comment: I have made a pull request with the changes discussed here: https://github.com/rxi/vec/pull/12 And I will open a new question with the content of section "Update C" in my original post. Thanks again!

Comment: @salocinx: Regarding which `, 0` to remove, the recommended code is shown at the end of my answer. Notably, the `, 0` should be inside the expression on the right side of the `:`.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil I asked regarding `vec_insert`, but I found the answer by searching with the commit number you posted. Pull request is initiated. I have been able to resolve the other problem described in section "Update C" by myself. Thanks again for your great answer; it gave me a lot of insight and studying C macros in more depth is my next goal.