# Why does the inner vector not get printed out?

Tags: c

I am experimenting with the C vector implementation [found here on Github](https://github.com/salocinx/vec). I have forked it from [rxi/vec](https://github.com/rxi/vec) and applied the small changes discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643222/how-to-solve-right-hand-operand-has-no-effect-error).

My current program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "vec.h"

typedef struct toc_element_t {
  uint16_t uid;
  char element[8];
  char type[8];
} toc_element_t;

typedef vec_t(toc_element_t) vec_toc_element_t;

typedef struct toc_item_t {
  char category[8];
  vec_toc_element_t elements;
} toc_item_t;

typedef vec_t(toc_item_t) vec_toc_item_t;

typedef struct toc_t {
    char description[8];
    vec_toc_item_t items;
} toc_t;


void app_main(void) {

    toc_t toc;
    strcpy(toc.description, "toc1");
    vec_init(&toc.items);

    toc_item_t item1;
    strcpy(item1.category, "cat1");
    vec_init(&item1.elements);
    vec_push(&toc.items, item1);

    toc_item_t item2;
    strcpy(item2.category, "cat2");
    vec_init(&item2.elements);
    vec_push(&toc.items, item2);

    toc_element_t elem1;
    elem1.uid=0;
    strcpy(elem1.element, "elem1");
    strcpy(elem1.type, "float");
    vec_push(&item1.elements, elem1);

    toc_element_t elem2;
    elem2.uid=1;
    strcpy(elem2.element, "elem2");
    strcpy(elem2.type, "float");
    vec_push(&item1.elements, elem2);


    printf("TOC [%s]:\n", toc.description);

    toc_item_t item; int index1;
    vec_foreach(&toc.items, item, index1) {
        printf(" - item[%d]=%s\n", index1, item.category);
        toc_element_t element; int index2;
        vec_foreach(&item.elements, element, index2) {
            printf("  - element[%d]=%s [%s]\n", index2, element.element, element.type);
        }
    }

    while(1);

}
```

**The output I get is:**

```
TOC [toc1]:
 - item[0]=cat1
 - item[1]=cat2
```

**But I would expect this:**

```
TOC [toc1]:
 - item[0]=cat1
  - element[0]=elem1
  - element[1]=elem2
 - item[1]=cat2
```

**What I am doing wrong ?**

Comment: https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasm-c-api/issues/55

Comment: The reason is, that `vec_push()` _copies_ the element to be pushed. So when you alter the original element, the copied element inside the vector remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the vector becomes immutable once you push it. This is because `vec_push` copies the element to be pushed, creating a new element in memory. Once you push item1 to toc.items, pushing elem1 to item1.elements only changes the local variable version of item1, not the version of item1 that exists in toc.items

To resolve the issue, `vec_push(&toc.items, item1);` anywhere after you push the last element to item1

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I accepted your answer as solution.

Comment: Perhaps you can find another phrase than "becomes immutable", since this is not the core of the issue. You _can_ change the vector element directly, so it is not immutable. But it is a copy of the original and changes to the original are not reflected in the vector item.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `vec_push(&toc.items, item1);` to the end solved the problem. Can somebody explain why?

```
toc_t toc;
strcpy(toc.description, "toc1");
vec_init(&toc.items);

toc_item_t item1;
strcpy(item1.category, "cat1");
vec_init(&item1.elements);

toc_item_t item2;
strcpy(item2.category, "cat2");
vec_init(&item2.elements);
vec_push(&toc.items, item2);

toc_element_t elem1;
elem1.uid=0;
strcpy(elem1.element, "elem1");
strcpy(elem1.type, "float");
vec_push(&item1.elements, elem1);

toc_element_t elem2;
elem2.uid=1;
strcpy(elem2.element, "elem2");
strcpy(elem2.type, "float");
vec_push(&item1.elements, elem2);

vec_push(&toc.items, item1);
```